# Haskell - Trouble with Parsing to Double

Tags: haskell

I hope you are doing very well.

I started doing some Haskell yesterday and today I got stuck on a function where I want to make an average of the length of every word. The problem that I have is that medellangd is always evaluated to be 0.0, no matter what. Both the variable *spaces* as well as the variable *listLength* are always 0.0, no matter what input is given.

```
medellangd :: String -> Double
spaces = fromIntegral (raknaBokstaver [] ' ')
listLength = fromIntegral (length [])

medellangd [] = 0.0
medellangd _ = (listLength-spaces) / (spaces + 1)
```

I tested the function *raknaBokstaver :: String -> Char -> Int*, in the terminal, and it worked just fine. The *length* function worked just as one would expect aswell.

Am I missusing the *fromIntegral* function? Why is it that *spaces* and *listLength* both are evaluated to 0.0?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uhm, spaces is declared as the constant `fromIntegral (raknaBokstaver [] ' ')` which does not depend on any input at all. Also, by definition, `medellangd` checks if the input list is empty, and returns the constant 0.0, otherwise it discards the input list (that's what `_` does) and returns another constant. I guess you want `medellangd xs = ...` where you do use the input list `xs` in some way.

Comment: Hello. Right, I got everything working as intended now, thank you very much for your response.

Comment: You're allowed to use åäö, by the way, unless your editor is horribly outdated.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want something similar to this (I tried to keep it close to your current solution):

```
medellangd :: String -> Double
medellangd [] = 0.0
medellangd xs = (listLength - spaces) / (spaces + 1) where
  spaces = fromIntegral (raknaBokstaver xs) 
  listLength = fromIntegral (length xs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I came across this _where_ keyword and the meaning of it earlier this weekend but I'll be using it more. Thanks for the reply, it really did help me.